# A degree $3$ complex polynomial with distinct critical points cannot have a repeated critical value

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

If $p(z)$ is a degree $3$ complex polynomial with distinct critical points (ie. zeros of $p'$), then the corresponding critical values must be distinct.

It is pretty easy to prove this using the level curves of $p$:

> **PROOF**: If the critical values were the same, then both critical points must lie in the same level curve $\Gamma$, so $\Gamma$ must have three faces, each of which must contain at least one zero of $p$ by the max. mod. theorem.
>   Let $D$ denote the one face of $\Gamma$ which has both of the critical points in its boundary.  Then since $p$ takes the same value twice on $\partial D$, the chance in the argument of $p(z)$ about $\partial D$ must be at least $2\pi$, and so $D$ must contain at least two zeros of $p$.  Thus $p$ has at least four zeros, a contradiction since $\deg(p)=3$.

My question is: Can someone give an analytic proof (perhaps using Cauchy Integral Formula or something) for this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they had the same critical value $y$ then $p(z)-y$ would have two distinct double roots, and this is impossible because it has degree $3$.

Comment: Well, that is much easier!